# Quicker way to save images to documents directory in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to save images to my apps documents directory. While I am easily able to save the images to the directory, its taking about two seconds to save an image and its thumbnail. I am using the following methods to save the images using a queue.

```
+ (void)saveImage:(UIImage*)imageToSave withName:(NSString*)imageName toFolder:(NSString*)folderName
{
    [Utils createFolderWithPath:folderName];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",folderName,imageName]];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageToSave);
    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
+ (void)createFolderWithPath:(NSString *)folderPath
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderPath];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
    }
}
```

is there a faster way? Since I have to save multiple images and 2 seconds per image is a lot of time!

Comment: You can save images in background thread and leave the main thread for other process. Also you can optimize your code by calculating document directory once and use it future use.

Comment: Did this stuff but still its taking time to save images. Saved the documents directory string in userdefaults once and used it all through. Any other ideas?

Comment: @SahilTyagi You missed the main idea he gave you. Use Background threads and blocks to write images. In the meanwhile, show a spinner to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to find the document directory every time. Just find out it one time and store it. and run your code in a thread, thread will save the image in background.